# Does $(\vec{a_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge? And if so, what is the limit?

Tags: convergence-divergence

If $\vec{a}$ is defined like this:
$$\vec{a_k}=\binom{\frac{1}{k+1}\cos{k}}{\;\;(k+1)\sin{(\frac{1}{k+1})}\;\;}$$
Does it then converge? And if so, what is the limit?
Any help on how to approach this problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I'm studying in german and got a bit confused. Changed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The expression $\frac{1}{k+1}$cos$(k)$ converges to 0 as $k\rightarrow \infty $ since $\frac{1}{k+1}$ approaches zero and cos $(k)$ just oscillates between -1 and 1. The expression $(k+1)$sin$(\frac{1}{(k+1)})$ approaches 1 as $k\rightarrow \infty$ since

$(k+1)$sin$(\frac{1}{(k+1)}) \approx \frac{k+1}{k+1}$ for large k.

Since each of its components converge, the vector function also converges to $(0,1)$ as $k\rightarrow \infty $

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does to $(0,1)$.Can you see why?